# No logro capturar valor de GET por medio de htaccess

Tags: php, apache

Estas son mis reglas de **.htaccess**

```
# Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

Options All -Indexes

# Url Amigables

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

la variable que envío es

```
<a href="editarfactura?action='.$item["numerofactura"].'" class="edit" ><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
```

y la muestro con:

```
echo $_GET['action'];
```

pero el get lo que me muestra es "editarfactura" en vez de lo que tiene la variable.

Comment: Cuando quieras ver el contenido de una variable, usa **var_dump()**, es decir, en lugar de *echo $_GET['action'];* pon *var_dump($_GET['action']);* obtendrás mas información. Saludos.

Comment: ya use var_dump. el problema radica en que la variable get recibe la pagina y no lo que viene el la variable url

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el `href="editarfactura?action='.$item["numerofactura"].'"` directamente por `href="'.$item["numerofactura"].'"`

con el `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?action=$1` creo que coges toda la url, entonces te aparece el aparece el `editarfactura`. Quizás hacer un: `RewriteRule ^editarfactura/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?action=$1` para que la url amigable sea  `href="editarfactura/'.$item["numerofactura"].'"`

No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar

Comment: si hago eso la pagina me deja de navegar y si hago lo de arriba no me redirecciona a la pagina

Comment: El tema, creo,  es que te coge `editarfactura` por que no esta bien formulada la regla. `RewriteRule ^editarfactura/(.+)$ index.php?action=$1` par apoder utilizar la url editarfactura/numerofactura. Me gustaría probarlo y decirtelo a ciencia cierta.

Comment: si coloco esta regla `^editarfactura/(.+)$ index.php?action=$1` deja de funcionar la navegacion de la pagina

Comment: Buscando Info, http://www.sinctrl.com/2008/04/14/%C2%BFque-son-las-rewrite-rules/ aqui aparece info que a lo mejor te es de ayuda. puede que utilizando las directivas `Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /` te funcione. Hechale un ojo